# Skeleton Tracking in ROS Indigo using Kinect

Tags: kinect, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm new to ROS and am using ROS indigo on 14.04 ubuntu.

The standard packages for skeleton tracking using kinect (openni_tracker, pi_tracker, nite) have not yet been updated to indigo. I'm hence to unable to download them via apt-get.

Is there any package I can use for skeleton tracking in indigo? Or is there any other way to install those packages?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190193/skeleton-tracking-in-ros-indigo-using-kinect/) by [DeepakP](https://answers.ros.org/users/20014/deepakp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2014-08-14

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [atp](https://answers.ros.org/users/5347/atp/) on 2014-08-15**:
What about downloading them from github directly and trying to compile them from source?

**Comment by [DeepakP](https://answers.ros.org/users/20014/deepakp/) on 2014-08-17**:
@atp I'd be grateful if you could walk me through the procedure.

**Comment by [ROS_Portland_State_University_Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/20663/ros_portland_state_university_robot/) on 2014-11-01**:
Could I get those unfinished packages or source? Our University robot must use Indigo. My task is to implement people-tracking. I will gladly try to compile the packages from sources if you tell me approximately what I need to do, give me high-level hints, etc. Or, could you post unfinished code?

**Comment by [ROS_Portland_State_University_Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/20663/ros_portland_state_university_robot/) on 2014-11-01**:
@atp said we could downlioad them form github directly and try to compile. Which packages are we to download?

**Comment by [Pourya](https://answers.ros.org/users/21761/pourya/) on 2015-03-08**:
I have a same problem with skeleton tracker package and ros indigo. Is there anyone to help?

**Comment by [marcobecerrap](https://answers.ros.org/users/1277/marcobecerrap/) on 2015-10-29**:
Hi, same here, has anyone come to the solution of this? i.e. how to use the skeleton tracker with ROS indigo & the Kinect?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!
Check [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/195459/skeletal-tracker-for-asus-xtion-pro-live/) post.

---

Originally posted by [Chaos](https://answers.ros.org/users/15091/chaos/) with karma: 396 on 2015-03-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

downloading them from github directly  does not work

---

Originally posted by [alain](https://answers.ros.org/users/23325/alain/) with karma: 11 on 2015-07-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Chaos](https://answers.ros.org/users/15091/chaos/) on 2015-07-24**:
Hello @alain! Have you trying with

```
git clone https://github.com/Chaos84/skeleton_tracker.git
```